# Better regular expression for ReverseStringFormat

Tags: c#, regex

I've been using for a while this neat function found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346158/parse-string-using-format-template) on SO:

```
    private List<string> ReverseStringFormat(string template, string str)
    {
        string pattern = "^" + Regex.Replace(template, @"\{[0-9]+\}", "(.*?)") + "$";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
        Match m = r.Match(str);

        List<string> ret = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
            ret.Add(m.Groups[i].Value);

        return ret;
    }
```

This function is able to process correctly templates like:

```
My name is {0} and I'm {1} years old
```

While it fails with patterns like:

```
My name is {0} and I'm {1:00} years old
```

I would like to handle this failing scenario and add fixed length parsing. 
The function transforms the (first) template as following:

```
My name is (.*?) and I'm (.*?) years old
```

I've been trying to write the above regular expression to limit the number of characters captured for the second group without success. This is my (terrible) attempt:

```
My name is (.*?) and I'm (.{2}) years old
```

I've been trying to process inputs like the following but the below PATTERN doesn't work:

```
PATTERN: My name is (.*?) (.{3})(.{5})
INPUT: My name is John 123ABCDE
EXPECTED OUTPUT: John, 123, ABCDE
```

Every suggestion is highly appreciated

Comment: what is your input and expected output?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just to re-order the actual arguments rather than the string format itself?

Comment: I've been using this function for a configurable parsing. I would like to extend it if possible... Maybe I don't understand what you mean with re-order actual parameters

Comment: Question updated with Input and expected output.

Comment: You need to include the template for your example, not the pattern.

Comment: @juharr is right. The only thing we know about the template is what already works and that `{1:00}` does not work, but really, `{1:00}` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've included the template but I was asking just for the regular expression. The function is included for reference. The {1:00} is the way string.Format uses to pad numbers. The ReverseStringFormat function I thought could use it to implement fixed length parsing. I hope it make sense :P

Comment: I don't think using a regular expression replace to create your regular expression is the best approach, especially when you need to turn `{1:000}` into `(.{3})`.

Comment: The problem is that (.{3}) does not work. I'm asking how to fix this regex

Comment: @dna2 it is strange, because (.{3}) should work... try testing on https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly unlikely that you will be able to measure the length of a captured group within the same Regex replacement.

I would strongly suggest you look at the following state machine implementation.
Please note that this implementation also solves the multiple curly brace escape feature of `string.Format`.

First you will need a state enum, very much like this one:

```
public enum State {
    Outside,
    OutsideAfterCurly,
    Inside,
    InsideAfterColon
}
```

Then you will need a nice way to iterate over each character in a string.
The `string chars` parameter represents your `template` parameter while the returning `IEnumerable<string>` represents consecutive parts of the resulting pattern:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> InnerTransmogrify(string chars) {
    State state = State.Outside;
    int counter = 0;

    foreach (var @char in chars) {
        switch (state) {
            case State.Outside:
                switch (@char) {
                    case '{':
                        state = State.OutsideAfterCurly;
                        break;
                    default:
                        yield return @char.ToString();
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case State.OutsideAfterCurly:
                switch (@char) {
                    case '{':
                        state = State.Outside;
                        break;
                    default:
                        state = State.Inside;
                        counter = 0;
                        yield return "(.";
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case State.Inside:
                switch (@char) {
                    case '}':
                        state = State.Outside;
                        yield return "*?)";
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        state = State.InsideAfterColon;
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
            case State.InsideAfterColon:
                switch (@char) {
                    case '}':
                        state = State.Outside;
                        yield return "{" + counter + "})";
                        break;
                    default:
                        counter++;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }

    }

}
```

You could join the parts like so:

```
public static string Transmogrify(string chars) {
    var parts = InnerTransmogrify(chars);
    var result = string.Join("", parts);
    return result;
}
```

And then wrap everything up, like you originally intended:

```
private List<string> ReverseStringFormat(string template, string str) {
    string pattern = <<SOME_PLACE>> .Transmogrify(template);
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
    Match m = r.Match(str);

    List<string> ret = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
        ret.Add(m.Groups[i].Value);

    return ret;
}
```

Hope you understand why the Regex language isn't expressive enough (at least as far as my understanding is concerned) for this sort of job.

Comment: You are a hero! It's hard to admit I understand only 50% of your answer but I'll study it!! Thanks :)

Comment: You could read about implementing state machines. Basically what we're doing is we are differentiating between 4 situations. These situations' names are self explanatory (look at the fields of the `enum`). Basically `Outside` means we are somewhere around here ">>My name is<<". Remember: we're iterating over each and every character, so when I say "we're here" I mean we're focusing on just One character. When we're `Inside` it means we're somewhere around here "{>>2:000<<}". Then look at the various combinations of Situation (state) X current char and things will be a bit clearer.

Comment: @EduardDumitru Actually, regex with balancing groups (or a stack) are expressive enough, and .NET implementation has those. See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/balancing.html

Comment: I've been debugging it and it's wonderful :) I've only found that you forgot in case State.Inside to include case ":" with change of state to InsideAfterColumn... After that is perfect! Thanks a lot!! And thanks for the neat code... I've been working with state machines but never on chars!!! This is a great usage of state machine!

Comment: Hei, copy pasted the wrong code from visual studio :). You are right. I guess, this way you digested the code a little more. I edited my answer to solve the Colon problem.

Comment: @FilipeBorges: That's great news, I had no idea. Could you please provide a simple example on how that can be accomplished? It would be great not just for the person who posted the question but for everyone who might end up reading it.

Comment: @EduardDimitru I will give a try later :-)

Comment: @EduardDumitru My other comment is very very wrong. For some reason I understood the problem was the balancing of parentheses and curly brackets. I am very sorry, man. Anyway, I suggested another solution using a custom matcher for the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to solve your problem with regular expressions is using a custom matcher to replace the group capture length.

The code bellow does this in your example:

```
private static string PatternFromStringFormat(string template)
{
    // replaces only elements like {0}
    string firstPass = Regex.Replace(template, @"\{[0-9]+\}", "(.*?)");
    // replaces elements like {0:000} using a custom matcher
    string secondPass = Regex.Replace(firstPass, @"\{[0-9]+\:(?<len>[0-9]+)\}",
        (match) =>
        {
            var len = match.Groups["len"].Value.Length;
            return "(.{" + len + "*})";
        });

    return "^" + secondPass + "$";
}

private static List<string> ReverseStringFormat(string template, string str)
{
    string pattern = PatternFromStringFormat(template);

    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
    Match m = r.Match(str);

    List<string> ret = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 1; i < m.Groups.Count; i++)
        ret.Add(m.Groups[i].Value);

    return ret;
}
```